# How to add Share button to the CommandBar of a Windows 10 Mobile UWP App and sharing capabilities to it?

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-phone, share

1. I'm trying to add a button to the command bar of a phone app (8.1 and UWP) with a typical Windows Phone share icon. How do I add such an icon to it?
2. I'd also like it to bring up the sharing window where the user can select the different ways of sharing something. It would share the link to my app in the store, like from the store app.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1: There is no share charm in Windows 10. What you can do is that you do the icon yourself. This would make it:

```
<AppBarButton Label="Share"  >
    <AppBarButton.Icon>
        <FontIcon FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Glyph="&#xE72D;"/>
    </AppBarButton.Icon>
</AppBarButton>
```

2:

In UWP I would use Share contract. (Basically the DataTransferManager class…)

Here is a good documentation for that:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/mt243293.aspx

Basically:

Hook up the event (e.g. in your page’s constructor..):

```
DataTransferManager.GetForCurrentView().DataRequested += MainPage_DataRequested;
```

Show the UWP share UI (e.g. on the button’s event handler..)

```
DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```

Do the sharing:

```
private void MainPage_DataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs args)
{
       args.Request.Data.SetWebLink(URI); 
       args.Request.Data.Properties.Title = "My new title";
       args.Request.Data.Properties.Description = "description";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Greg. I will try this. Do you know of a way to add a share icon to a command bar button, like the one that the Store app or the Photos app has (Three small circles connected by a large circle)?

Comment: Well…there is no Share Charm in windows 10… 
What you can do is something like this: <AppBarButton Icon="IconName" > Here are the default icons: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.symbol.aspx what you are looking for is unfortunately not in the list.. one option would be to do it yourself by adding <AppBarButton.Icon> to the AppBarButton.

Comment: I Updated my answer... there is a sample for doing the icon with AppBarButton.Icon.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Both solutions work fine. I'd mention, though, that instead of SetUri, SetWebLink must be used. SetUri may become altered or unavailable in future releases. Thanks again.

Comment: Good point!! (The documentation also stated this...) I edited my answer.